# Am I iterating through my json data correctly?

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON data I read from a file that looks like this:

```
{
 "books":
        {
         "20":
             {
              "id":"10874",
              "title":"Measurement of ...
```

I do not know what "20" means. I assume it some sort of key that I really don't care about.  I care about the data "after" the "20".  So I do this ...

```
for bk, junk in parsed['books'].iteritems():
    book_key = bk 
print book_key
print "------------------\n"
print parsed['books'][book_key]['title']
```

Although this works, it bothers me that I am using a for loop just to get a key.
I am sure I am not doing this right.

Thanks

Comment: can't you do directly `parsed['books']["20"]['title']` ?

Comment: I assume the `20` is arbitrary.

Comment: how about `junk['title']`

Comment: Presumably it won't always be `20`.

Comment: if you don't know keys then you have to use `for` loop. If there is only one key they you could do `book_key = parsed['books'].keys()[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
book_key = parsed['books'].keys()[0]
print parsed['books'][book_key]['title']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one key then you could do

```
 book_key = parsed['books'].keys()[0]
```

or even (using `.items()` instead of `.keys()`)

```
 book_key, val = parsed['books'].items()[0]

 print book_key
 print val['title']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

a1="""{ "books": { "20": { "id":"10874", "title":"Measurement of SPEED"},\
                   "30": { "id":"10874", "title":"Measurement of LENGTH"}}}"""

for b in json.loads(a1)['books'].values():
    print b['title']
```

Output:

```
Measurement of SPEED
Measurement of LENGTH
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the title of the first (and only) book directly:

```
print parsed['books'].values()[0]['title']
```

Python 3:

```
print(list(parsed['books'].values())[0]['title'])
```